# spring mvc hibernate creating and manipulating sessionfactorys of several databases

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, multiple-databases, sessionfactory

here I have a problem that I want to find a solution here, I work on a project using spring mvc and hibernate in my project I have several databases with same architecture (database by company) and a database for authentication, when the user login i have to generates a SessionFactory that corresponds to database of the user company, can you help me by offering me an architecture and give me some examples please, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on which hibernate version you use you can just utilize the built in multi tenant features of hibernate. For that you need to implement the `CurrentaTenantIdentifierResolver` and `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` following this documentation[this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)

the following hibernateProperties have to be set additionaly to use them:

```
                hibernate.multiTenancy=DATABASE
                hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver=xxx.xxx.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl
                hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider=xxx.xxx.MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl
```

**Sample Implementation:**
CurrentTenantIdentifier:

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver;

public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {



    @Override
        public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
            if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().yourOwnRoutineToDetermineCompanyxxx=="companyxxx"){
                return "companyxxx";

            } else  if ... furhter companies{
                ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
            return true;
        }

    }
```

MultiTenantConnectionProvider:

```
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractMultiTenantConnectionProvider {
    @Autowired
    private DataSoruce DScompany02;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource DScompany01;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource default;

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider getAnyConnectionProvider() {
        return new DatasourceConnectionProvider(default);
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionProvider selectConnectionProvider(String tenantIdentifier) {
         if (tenantidentifer == "company01"){
        return new DatasourceConnectionProvider(DScompany01);
         } repeat....
    }
}
```

now just define a datasource per company DB so it can be swapped by the multitenantconnectionprovider.

A call to the sessionFactory in the DAO can be made by using `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` or in special cases by using `sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("company01").openSession()`

This should cover the basics but might need some tayloring to your application.

Comment: Hi Carsten, thank you for reply, i use spring 3.2.2-RELEASE with hibernate 4.2, for exemple the user from companyxxx is authenticated, and now i have to create au session factory who connect to url "localahost:3306/dbcompanyxxx", how to do that, in my DAO i have to do somthing like public List<Model> getModel(){SessionFactory sesseionFactory = SessionManager.getSessionFactory(user.getIdCompany(); .....} can you developpe your answer please

Comment: Elaborated the answer a bit.

Comment: ok thanks, when i use openSession it work, but i willnot have a probleme with read or write in the databases ?

Comment: No, the session you get is opened with the (for that instance) relevant DB connection. On this sesion you can do everything you can with a "standard" hibernate implementation.

Comment: Thanks for solution, i will use this :-)