# Multi-tenancy in Hibernate - multi databases (SQLite)

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to do multi-tenancy with multi databases. From this [chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html#d5e4691) I took **MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl**.

And here I have problem. Eclipse cannot find class **ConnectionProviderUtils**. I'm using Maven with dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hate to disapoint you but I was running in the same problem a while back. The point is the ConnectionProviderUtil is quite misleading in the documentation. There is no such thing. The ConnectionProviderUtil is something you have to implement yourself. I implemented this by constructing my own `DataSource` (a c3p0 pooled one) in the MultiTenantConnectionProvider and handing out connection from there.

So you have to implement it from scratch yourself. For reference here is my way to a Solution. [Setting up a MultiTenantConnectionProvider using Hibernate 4.2 and Spring 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213573/setting-up-a-multitenantconnectionprovider-using-hibernate-4-2-and-spring-3-1-1)

For the multi DB approach you can just autowire the different `DataSources` into the `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` and switch based on the TenantIdentifier. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16769595/2319179

**Edit:**
If you use Spring you can set up a DataSource in the appcontext like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="<jdbcdriver>" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:SQLServer://<host>:<port>;databaseName=<dbname>" />
            <property name="username" value="<user>" />
            <property name="password" value="<pw>" />
       </bean>
```

If you need to build it from java you can do it like this:

```
        cpds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(<jdbc.driver>);
cpds.setJdbcUrl(<jdbc.url>);
cpds.setUser("<user>");
cpds.setPassword("<pw>"));
```

A quick googlesearch should bring up the right driver.

Comment: How can I create DataSource for SQLite? Is there any given things or I need to code everything?

Comment: I see that DriverManagerDataSource is only in Spring. Can I do it somehow in Java SE?

Comment: there should be the java.sql.DataSource available. Which is also the core of the DriverManagerDataSource.

Comment: When you creating new tenanct where you creating new database (and all tables)?

Comment: For a lack of a better solution for now I am using native SQL and JDBCTemplate to create a new Schema/DB. The tables are usualy created as outlined in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16807512/2319179

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionProvider` is what you use to customize your strategy for obtaining connections. Provided all schemas are the same, this is one of the best places to implement multi-tenancy.

Along with the `ConnectionProvider`, you'll need a `ThreadLocal` to hold the "tenancy" and probably a `ServletFilter` to set it up (from session variable, set at login). This is similar to how Spring's `OpenSessionInViewFilter` works.

All in all, this can provide a very simple & effective solution:

http://literatejava.com/hibernate/multi-tenancy-architecture-with-hibernate/