# How to create database in Hibernate at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate tenancy and every time user logs I'm changing database to his username (SQLite). Sadly sometimes the database does not exists and I need to create it.

The problem is that I don't know how to create all tables in database at runtime.

Normally Hibernete creates for me db with this:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Comment: Create a new `SessionFactory` from scratch just like you create the initial one?

Comment: session = sessionFactory.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("tenancy_id").openSession(); <- but where I should add this?

Comment: I don't think the database update runs when you open a session. It runs when you create a `SessionFactory`. When switching databases, you'll have to get rid of the old factory, and create it anew. I have no idea *where* to do this because I have no idea where you're doing it *now*.

Comment: I hope it helps you. It works for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069687/hibernate-auto-create-database/26706954#26706954

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SchemaExport for this to export the entities you want to create in your newly created database right after you created the database. the basic steps are below. How you get the properties for your config does not really matter.

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Class1.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Class2.class);
    config.addAnnotatedClass(Class3.class);
    <set all hibernate properties/datasource here>
    SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(config);
    schema.create(true, true);
```

Javadocs are here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html

For options of setting upt the configuration look here. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html

**Edit:**
I guess a remark that has to be added is that it is considered bad practice to let hibernate handle DB/SCHEMA/TABLE creation in a production environment. Depending on the needs and the viability it might be better practice to save prepared SQL statements for this, or even do it manualy by a DB admin. But since we are all lazy I guess thats not often going to happen. ;D

Comment: Can I get my classes from hibernate.cfg.xml? Like config.loadAnnotatedClassFromXML()?

Comment: Yes. Just pick the method that suist you best from here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html. You probably want to look into addClass() or addFile().

Answer (score 4):

Did you try the value `create` instead.

> A value of create will create your tables at sessionFactory creation, and leave them intact.
>
> A value of create-drop will create your tables, and then drop them when you close the sessionFactory.

That would be

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

More infornation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306806/hibernate-automatically-creating-updating-the-db-tables-based-on-entity-classes)
Or there could be a [dialect problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291940/hibernate-does-not-create-tables-automatically)

Comment: The problem is that database is created at runtime (I'm using tenance)

Answer (score 3):

You can create database at run time by adding `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` parameter in DB connection URL.

For more information check the [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31422939/6830615) !