# Hibernate auto create database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a Java EE Hibernate project, and I'm using MySQL as a database.

I want that when I first time run the project, it will create the database automatically.

This is my `hibernate.cnf.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/InternetProject</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="entities.Business" />
        <mapping class="entities.Coupon" />
        <mapping class="entities.User" />
        <mapping class="entities.LastLogin" />
    </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I first time run this project on another computer, how can I make the database `InternetProject` to be created?

According to the config file, it might already do it and I'm not aware to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 58):

> `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>` 
>       will create tables. But it will not create database. Change the connection url to generate the database.
>
> ```
> <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
> <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/InternetProject?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>
> <property name="connection.username">root</property>
> <property name="connection.password"></property>
> <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
> ```

Update : character encoding when creating database

```xml
<property name="connection.url">
    jdbc:mysql://localhost/InternetProject?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
</property>
```

Comment: If you put a value in the property 'password', is automatically set and used?

Comment: Yes. hibernate will do automatically.

Comment: how can i set the character encoding when creating database?

Comment: Use jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/footballdb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 13):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

will do

Comment: Thanks! when is the difference between this and `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`?

Comment: create will create a new schema and update will look for the schema and do the update

Comment: I can use `create` instead of `udpate` , or should I use both?

Comment: just create is enough for the first time and then change it back to update for future

Comment: @yyny: this will not create database from my experience. If database is there, it will create tables. Thats only. Any other way?

Comment: this xml sintax doesnt validate. cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty

Answer (score 8):

Hibernate will not create the database for you, only the tables. To create the database you need to tell MySQL to create it if it does'nt already exist by adding a parameter to the URL. E.g.:

```
jdbc:mysql://db:3306/mydatabase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

Comment: I really like this solution, but it does not work for me. I get `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple option for auto property.

1. create - It creates new tables corresponding mapping or annotation. It drops existing tables and data.
2. update - It keeps existing data and tables. It updates schema. here we have to take care contrants.
3. create-drop - It is same like create but once session gets closed it drops everything.
4. validate - it validates or matches schema with map or annotation. It's valid for Production environment.

   ```
   <!-- create create-drop validate update -->
   <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
   ```

I hope it helps.