# Database configuration with Spring boot needs to be in web to work properly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle11g

I'm working on a web based application with Spring boot and Oracle 11g. 
The application is split to 4 Maven Modules which are:

Model - in which are declared all Entities.
Persistence - in which i have Spring data's repositories. 
Domain - in which i have All services.
Web - in which i have MVC.

So in my persistence project I have application.properties which looks like this:

```
spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=MOVIE_CATALOG
spring.datasource.password=MOVIE_CATALOG
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

If the database is created it works fine but if the database is not created and i expect Hibernate to do this for me I receive an exception like this:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException:
>   Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type
>   NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on
>   the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a
>   particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are
>   currently active).

I find out that if I put database configuration in Web's application.properties the project work fine too but I don't want to do this.

Any ideas why this exception occurred?

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? I'm wondering where your application.properties file is.

Comment: I have 2 application.properties. The first one is in Persistence where i want to define database configuration. The second one is in web where i want to define web configuration like server.port and others. The both files are in src/main/resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're booting your application from Web then the local application.properties file replaces the one in Persistence, as opposed to merging.

A Solution would be to rename one of the files and specify them both in  @PropertySource on your @Configuration classes.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate can auto create tables, but not a whole data base. Create an empty database for Hibernate to build the tables.

[Similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069687/hibernate-auto-create-database)

[Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases) Only mentions creating and dropping tables.

Comment: I have schema in Oracle which is called MOVIE_CATALOG but when I start application hibernate does not create tables, sequences and indexes. So i do not expect hibernete  to create the whole database. Just tables, sequence and indexes

Comment: @PetarPetrov Hmm. I'll keep thinking on it. If I have an idea, I'll post it.